# SwiftUI: How to update detail column from a distant child using iOS16/iPadOS16 NavigationSplitView and NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, ios16, swiftui-navigationsplitview, ipados16

I'm trying to update an older app to use the new NavigationSplitView and NavigationLink, but trying to wrap my head around the proper way to do it when the sidebar has a hierarchy of child objects and I want to update the detail view from a distant child object. For example, based on the WWDC2022 example project Navigation Cookbook I tried the following and it didn't work:

> TestApp.swift

```
@main

struct TestApp: App {
  @StateObject var appState = AppState()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {

      NavigationSplitView {
         ProjectListView()
      } detail: {
        if let chapter = appState.chapter {
          ChapterDetailView(chapter: chapter)
        } else {
          Text("Pick a Chapter")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> ChapterListView.swift < A distant (3 levels down) sibling of ProjectListView()

```
List(selection: $appState.chapter) {
  ForEach(chapters) { chapter in
    NavigationLink(chapter.title ?? "A Chapter", value: chapter)
  }
}
```

> appState.swift

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var chapter: Chapter?
}
```

I'm sure I'm just not understanding the basics of how the new way of doing navigation works. Yes, I am targeting iOS16

Comment: Placing of StateObject inside WindowGroup closure is senseless. See that WWDC session one more time and then review code for it.

Comment: @Asperi Sorry, copy and paste error. I fixed it. I am reviewing code for that session and this is very similar to what they do. The only big difference (that I can see) is that I'm trying to update the StateObject from a distant child. All of their code is included at the top level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug in beta 1. To workaround, the logic in the detail section needs to be wrapped in a ZStack. From the release notes:

Conditional views in columns of NavigationSplitView fail to update on some state changes. (91311311)
Workaround: Wrap the contents of the column in a ZStack. TestApp works if changed to this:

```
@main

struct TestApp: App {
  @StateObject var appState = AppState()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {

      NavigationSplitView {
         ProjectListView()
      } detail: {
// Wrap in a ZStack to fix this bug
       ZStack {
        if let chapter = appState.chapter {
          ChapterDetailView(chapter: chapter)
        } else {
          Text("Pick a Chapter")
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```